# Having space problem while using phpfmt [code formatter] with ...$variable_name

Tags: php, vscode-extensions, code-formatting

Here is my example code where i am having error while using phpfmt [code formatter].

```
function ( int | float...$numbers ): int | float {
    return array_sum( $numbers );
};
```

Here as we can see in the function parameter i am using Variable-length argument lists ... using this token, i am also declare the type of the variable.
Now when i am trying to save it, phpfmt code formatter make the type and ... token together which i don't want, it is create confusion for other code readers.

How can i fix that issue please help me with this as i am new to php coding.

I am using vscode as my code editor.

Here i am also provide my phpfmt vscode settings.

```
 "editor.formatOnSave": true,
 "phpfmt.passes": ["AlignDoubleArrow", "SpaceAroundParentheses"],
 "phpfmt.psr2": false,
```

I go through the phpfmt command list but i can't find any specific command for that.

I am also watch some phpfmt videos but those all are similar just showing the installation process.

Comment: Normally, for a tool used in another tool, you would [check the documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt), and if you cannot find it, and think this is a bug, or there should be an option to configure it, you would [open an issue on github](https://github.com/kokororin/vscode-phpfmt/issues). Here we are more adept at answering question about writing code itself, and not so much at answering question about the tools in which you write your code.

Comment: thanks @KIKOSoftware for answering my question, you are absolutely right our purpose should be help with the codes. as i am a beginner so thought the experts can solve this small issues within a sec that is why i asked. I go through  that documentation but can not find a solution. If you already noticed it in that doc please let me know it will help me a lot. Thanks once again i will raise a issue on github if needed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for suggest me to raise a issue on github, they fixed that issue.
https://github.com/kokororin/vscode-phpfmt/issues/141